# How to return nested function value in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I got stuck in getting the result return from the function for authentication the user.

```
utility.isAspAuth = function(token){
    queryString = {
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM SecurityToken WHERE Token = ?',
        timeout: 40000, // 40s
        values: [token]
    };
    var curTime = new Date();
    connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows,field){
        if(err){
            console.log('error on query' + err);
        }else{

            var result = rows[0];

            result.forEach(function(element, index, array){
                if(Date.parse(result.Expires) > curTime){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

so I call this function in another file, but the result is undefined

```
console.log(utility.isAspAuth(token))
```

can someone give me some hint on how to fix it?

Thank you so much

Comment: Async, async, async.  Your `connection.query()` function is asynchronous.  That means it calls it's callback sometime LATER, long after `isAspAuth()` has already returned.  You cannot return an asynchronous value from a function like this.  Instead, you must pass a callback into `isAspAuth()` and call that callback when you have your final value and you can only use the value from that callback.  There are hundreds of dups of this type of question.  I will go looking for one to mark this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue is:**

When you call `utility.isAspAuth(token)` from another file your function in `utility` file is getting execute but not returning anything at the time of call.

This is nature of nodejs. Notice in your code -

`connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows,field){`

only after query is done your callback function in above line gets executed, which wont' happen serially. It's asyn by default. This is why you're getting `nothing` ie. `undefined` in your `console.log()`.

**Fix is:**

Use **promises** -

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

> > If a function cannot return a value or throw an exception without blocking, it can return a promise instead."

In your utility file -

```
utility.isAspAuth = function(token){

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    /* require('q') in your nodejs code.
       You see at the last line of this function we return a promise object.
       And in your success / fail function we either resolve/ reject the promise. 
       Simple. See the usage in other file where you log.
    */

    queryString = {
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM SecurityToken WHERE Token = ?',
        timeout: 40000, // 40s
        values: [token]
    };
    var curTime = new Date();
    connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows,field){
        if(err){
            // console.log('error on query' + err);

            deferred.reject(new Error(err));

        } else {

            var result = rows[0];

            result.forEach(function(element, index, array){
                if(Date.parse(result.Expires) > curTime){

                    deferred.resolve(true);

                }else{

                    deferred.resolve(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });


     return deferred.promise;

};
```

In your other file-

```
utility.isAspAuth(token)
.then(function (yourBoolResponse) {

    console.log(yourBoolResponse);
})
.catch(function (err) {

    // Handle error thrown here..
})
.done();
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions for which there are many, many duplicates.  Instead, just vote to close as a duplicate.  This just pollutes the StackOverflow world if there are lots of duplicates all asking the same question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes, 'll keep this in mind from now onwards. Thanks btw for pointing.